# OCaml how to choose between repeated type constructors

Tags: types, constructor, functional-programming, ocaml, anonymous-function

In Ocaml, I am using the same type constructor name in two type definitions. Like:

```
type a=
     ...
   | The_constructor of ... 
   |  ...

type b:
     ...
   | The_constructor of ... 
   |  ...
```

When I use it as `(fun x-> The_constructor(x))`, the_constructor is directly assigned to be 'b' (guess it is because it is the last one), but I want it to be 'a'. Is it here a way to do it? I tried something like `(a.The_constructor)` but does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another solution might be to give the constructors different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, if disambiguation cannot be sure, you will get the latest defined constructor. As Anthony pointed out, you can add disambiguation by defining your types in modules. You can also add type annotations to help the typing system.

```
(* y has type `a` *)
let y : a = The_constructor x

(* a function from "whatever" to type `a` *)
((fun x -> The_constructor x) : _ -> a)

(* f returns a `a` (same function as the other one) *)
let f x : a = The_constructor x
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the types in different modules:

```
module A = struct
  type t=
    ...
    | The_constructor of ... 
    | ...
end 

module B = struct
  type t=
    ...
    | The_constructor of ... 
    | ...
end
```

and then you can choose which type you want as:

```
let a = A.The_constructor x in
let b = B.The_constructor x in
...
```